# Get CurrentPage of ReportViewer in Print Preview mode?

Tags: c#, data-binding, report, reportviewer, localreport

In normal mode (by default at the first time loading ReportViewer with Local Report), I can get the CurrentPage correctly which is the current page in the current view mode.

But after changing to Preview mode (can be done using `SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)`), I can't get the value of CurrentPage which is the only property I can access to know the current page of the ReportViewer. I need to achieve this because I want to customize my own Toolbar for the reportviewer, it has almost been done except that the CurrentPage seems to be fixed to 1 after switching to PrintLayout mode.

Here is my code to display current page:

```
private void BindData(){
   myTextBox.DataBindings.Clear();
   myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myReportViewer, "CurrentPage");
}
//Register some events to re-bind data and get other updated info (such as TotalPages)...
myReportViewer.RenderingComplete += (s,e) => {
     BindData();
};
myReportViewer.PageSettingsChanged += (s,e) => {
     BindData();
};
```

That works OK when in normal mode (the PageSettingsChanged handler is added for switching to PrintLayout mode but it doesn't seem to work, it does help update the TotalPages which can be achieved using GetTotalPages() method, however the binding doesn't work anymore after switching to PrintLayout mode).

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The CurrentPage isn't been fixed to 1

The problem here is RenderingComplete doesn't get called if you swap the page
you need to use the [PageNavigationevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.pagenavigation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
myReportViewer.PageNavigation += myPageNavigation

void myPageNavigation(object sender, PageNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("CurrentPage will be" +e.NewPage);
}
```